# I want the stream builder to run when I press the button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I will check firebase firestore data with streamBuilder and draw widgets. But I want streambuilder to run when I press the button, how can I do that?

Comment: Please read this and then update your question appropriately => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you can have a boolean variable, let's say `isClicked` and initialize it with false. Now, when you are clicking on the button, set the boolean variable to true.

The place where you write StreamBuilder, you can add an if condition to check the value of `isClicked`